# Calling an ASP.NET FileUpload function in code behind with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I'm using the ASP.NET FileUpload control.

To upload a file, a user must:

1. Browse to select a file from his/her device,
2. Click the upload button to upload the file to the server.

Is it possible to skip step 2 (the Upload button) and call the 'uploadFile_Click' function on the server through a jquery (postback) once a file is selected? I'm trying the following method but I need some help to finalize it.

ASPX PAGE

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UploadImages" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUpload" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Upload code
}
```

JQUERY

```
function ValidateUpload() {
var FileUpload_function = document.getElementById('UploadImages');

        if (FileUpload_function.value == '') {
            return false;
        }
        else {

           ** Here I want to trigger a postback to call the uploadFile_Click. Is that possible? **
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: So my approach has a dead end...?

Comment: Usually when you want to do anything more than just the basic select a file and click upload, you gotta roll your own solution. There are some premade solutions that you can try, most of which rely on ajax calls to process the upload and have features like visual upload progress, drag and drop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some (most?) browsers will not allow you to call the click event on an `input` HTML element if it is of type `file` (ie. an asp:fileupload control). It is considered a security risk.

Comment: Even if it does work it won't include the file data when posting the form. Same reason.